# One click() counts as 11 events in Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to track a simple search form click in Google Analytics.

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Search Location', 'Click', 'Search Location');
}); 

<form action="#" id="myform" class="uk-form" onSubmit="getbases2(); return false;">                                                 
<input type="text" id="search" class="uk-form-width-medium">                                              
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="SearchButton" class="uk-button uk-button-success   search-button" />
</form>
```

Each click on this button counts as 11 events in Analytics. When I changed the method to mousedown, each click count as 7 events. How can I set this up so each click on the button counts as only one event?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing [OmniBug Plugin for Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/omnibug/) as this will show you the number of requests being made to Google.

Unless you have jQuery (or similar) triggers setup to trigger clicks on the `#SearchButton` then your code should work and only send one event for one click. However, are you sure you don't have other code clicking that button for you?

For debugging purposes, load the page, open up Omnibug, hit `Persist` so you don't lose everything in the console when the page reloads and then perform a search. You should only see *one* request to Google, for your one event?

Also, is it an issue to change from Universal Analytics back to Google Analytics should this be an issue?